# test for existing row.names and col.names in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, attributes

Is there a function to determine whether a data.frame has native row names and column names or just has automatically generated ones (1 2 3 4...) ? For column names, '*automatically*' means for instance when you apply "as.data.frame" to a matrix..

For the row names, I figured out a workaround:

```
has.row.names = function(df) {
  !all(row.names(df)==seq(1, nrow(df)))
}
```

However, for for the column names i don't see how to do it. The difficulty is that sometimes automated col.names start with V1 V2 etc, sometimes with X1., X2..

Why I ask this question: I need to perform this test inside a more complex function (somewhat similar to the graphical output of a PCA) that will plot the row names and column names if existing, and if not it will create more suited new names.
So it should work for "any" data.frame, with no clue of the actual names.

Comment: What's the purpose? Will you really do something different depending if it's automatically generated or not? Does it need to work on any data frame? If just ones created with read.table, then using read.table more precisely could probably tell you.

Comment: yes, needs to work for any df. that's why i don't know them in advance. And i don't want the automatically generated col and row names, it will be a mess for the plot.

Comment: The function `has_rownames` in the `tibble` package now does the trick for row names

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short version:** The only time a data frame would not have column names is when the attribute "names" is NULL. So the simple way to check for the existence of column names in a data frame would be something like the following.

```
DFHasColNames <- function(x) {
    stopifnot(is.data.frame(x))
    Negate(is.null)(names(x))
}
DFHasColNames(mtcars)
# [1] TRUE
DFHasColNames(unname(mtcars))
# [1] FALSE
```

**Extended version:** For row names, you can use `.row_names_info()`.  With the default `type = 1L`, a negative sign indicates the row names were generated automatically.

```
.row_names_info(mtcars)
# [1] 32   # row names were provided 
.row_names_info(iris)
# [1] -150 # row names were generated automatically
```

You can also view other information by changing the `type` argument.

> **type** integer. Currently type = 0 returns the internal "row.names" attribute (possibly NULL), type = 2 the number of rows implied by the attribute, and type = 1 the latter with a negative sign for ‘automatic’ row names.

```
.row_names_info(mtcars, type = 0)
## ... returns attr(mtcars, "row.names")
.row_names_info(iris, type = 0)
## [1]   NA -150
```

For column names, it's not so easy.   Generally speaking, if you see all `NA` values for the column names, or `names(x)` returns `NULL`, the "names" attribute of `x` is not set and therefore `x` has no (column) names.

Otherwise, a prepended `X` usually means the names came from `make.names()`, which is used by `data.frame()` and `read.table()`, `read.csv()` and others.

```
m <- matrix(1:6, 2)
make.names(seq_len(ncol(m)))
# [1] "X1" "X2" "X3"
data.frame(m)
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  3  5
# 2  2  4  6
```

whereas you generally get a prepended `V` from `as.data.frame()`

```
as.data.frame(m)
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  3  5
# 2  2  4  6
```

However, this is not a rule. It depends on the class of the object you're passing to `as.data.frame()`, and whether or not you have changed any of the default arguments.  The best thing to do would be to sift through the many `methods(as.data.frame)` to see if you can discover a pattern.

Comment: What does it mean when `.row_names_info(x)` returns 0? It’s unfortunately not documented …

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Not certain, but I think it means that the data has no rows to begin with.  See `.row_names_info(data.frame())`, it returns 0.

Comment: No, the data (a matrix) has rows, and row names. My problem is that this apparently screws up `tibble::as_tibble`; if I read its code correctly, it should do something with the row names of a matrix before converting but it just drops them, and by tracing the code I found the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Use exists
with(mtcars,exists("cyl"))
[1] TRUE

with(mtcars,exists("cy"))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: thanks for the "exists" function that i did not know. but it needs to be automated, i don't know in advance the names.

Comment: for every col in `tab1`, test if it is found in `tab2`: `cn <- colnames(tab1); sapply(cn, function(x) { with(tab2, exists(x))});`

Comment: simpler: `missingCols <- setdiff(colnames(tab1), colnames(tab2))`